# How do I apply XSL transforms on the command line using Java 8?

Tags: java, xslt

I've successfully applied an XSL transform on the command line using what is described [here](https://numberformat.wordpress.com/2010/03/20/java-command-line-xslt-transformation/), but the example only seems to work on Java 6 or older. I keep seeing examples saying I should use `com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.Process` as the cli, but when I try that I only get: `Error: Main method not found in class com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xslt.Process`

Is there a way to apply XSL transformations on the command line in Java 8, or have they simply removed that?

I work in an airgapped environment so any solutions that involves downloading anything won't work. I only have access to JDKs and JREs.

Comment: try to locate xalan*.jar in the java installation and try to call it with `java -jar ...` or download xalanj from xalan.apache.org and use that

Comment: Sorry, should've mentioned that I work in an airgapped environment and can't download anything. But I'll give looking for the xalan jar a shot.

Answer (score 0):

This is a different approach to the one you have referred. Unless you are compelled for some reason to pre-compile the XSLT to a Java class, you may use this as well. The benefit of this approach is that your code is agnostic to different JAXP XSLT implementations.

Try the following for the java code where you load the XSLT and apply it to an XML file

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer(xsltAsDomSource);
transformer.transform(inputXmlSource, outputXmlResult);
```

Run it as a jar or as a class from CLI as usual. JDK8 will use a pre-packed, default XSLT processor if you just say:

```
java -jar yourJarName.jar
```

However if you wanted more control with using a specific XSLT processor, you could use the "javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory" parameter to specify the implementation class of your choice. Read the [JDK8 TransformerFactory API Doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) to understand better.

Comment: Heh sweet, didn't think of that. Of course that would work, I'll give it a whirl!